# How can I create an iCal realtime backup?

Tags: icloud, backup, ical

I'd like to create an event in iCal and either 1) save it to multiple calendars, such as create an iCloud event and have it save simultaneously to another calendar, or 2) upon creating an iCloud calendar event, have it automatically copied to a different calendar.  This is more or less the same thing, but makes one think about it in different ways.

Basically, I want a realtime backup for my iCloud calendar.  I don't know applescript but I could probably learn it - I've done a lot of php, javascript and actionscript coding - I'm just not sure applescript would be the way to go.  Any advice appreciated. Maybe I'm looking at this in the wrong way.
Thanks, Klaus

Answer (score 1):

Maybe merging iCloud, local, and Gmail all together and then having Time Machine?

Your thoughts (dare I say paranoia) are interesting and the goal, unique. You could also create a script that runs at a set time interval and fetches your calendars and archives them in a method of your choosing.

Maybe the simplest would be to create an Automator script that will fetch your iCloud calendars and then save it to your ideal location and archive it automatically. The file of your calendar can be pulled when you go into iCal.app and then obtain the URL for sharing the calendar. Copy that URL and change "webcal://p20-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/..." to "http://p20-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/subscribe/..."

That should fit the bill and keep system and effort to a minimum.